# How to change git repository of toolchain after owner change

Tags: ibm-cloud

I made myself the owner of a toolchain in someone else's space and need to change the git repo. I can see the toolchain and select "Input type", "Builder Type" etc.. How do I add a new Git repository and Git URL (greyed out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can try changing the GitHub repo URL

- Navigate to your created toolchain, On the Overview page of the
  toolchain, hover over the Delivery Pipeline card.
- Click Delivery Pipeline.
- You need to update the Build stage. Click the gear on the BUILD stage
  and select Configure Stage.
- Click the INPUT table and change the Git Repository.
- Click Save and click the run icon to start the BUILD stage.

For more details, you can check [here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/tutorials/change-git-provider-in-a-toolchain?task=2)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21549485)

Comment: @Nick Edited the answer